# Reflection in JavaScript: How to intercept an object for function enhancement, decoration and delegation?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create an interceptor of function calls upon an object without any modification of the object itself?

```
function intercept(obj) {    
    ???

    function onFunctionCall(funcName, funcArgs) { ... }
}

var obj = {};
var interceptedObj = intercept(obj);

interceptedObj.someFunc(1, 2, 3);
```

This could be used to enhance the object:

```
function onFunctionCall(funcName, funcArgs) {
    if ('fn1' === funcName) {
        return /* something */
    }
    if ('fn2' === funcName) {
        return /* something */
    }
    throw new Error(`Function ${funcName} is not supported.`);
}
```

Or to decorate the call:

```
function onFunctionCall(funcName, funcArgs) {
    console.debug(`Function ${funcName} started.`);
    const returnValue = obj[funcName].apply(obj, funcArgs);
    console.debug(`Function ${funcName} finished.`);
    return returnValue;
}
```

Or to delegate:

```
const delegateObj = new ....

function onFunctionCall(funcName, funcArgs) {
    return delegateObj[funcName].apply(delegate, funcArgs);
}
```

Comment: I don't think so, you'll have to make a separate object and call that object, or mutate the existing object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Proxy object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

```js
function intercept(obj) {        
    return new Proxy(obj, {
        get: function(target, prop) {
            return typeof target[prop] !== 'function'
                ? target[prop]
                : (...args) => onFunctionCall(prop, args);                    
        }
    });
    
    function onFunctionCall(funcName, funcArgs) { 
        console.debug(`Function '${funcName}' started.`);
        const returnValue = obj[funcName].apply(obj, funcArgs);
        console.debug(`Function '${funcName}' finished.`);        
        return returnValue;
    }
}

var obj = { 
  attr0: 0,
  attr1: 1,
  attr2: null,
  myfn1: (...args) => console.log('executing myfn1 with', args),
  myfn2: async (...args) => console.log('executing myfn2 with', args)  
};
var interceptedObj = intercept(obj);

console.log('ATTR0', interceptedObj.attr0)  // 0
console.log('ATTR1', interceptedObj.attr1)  // 1
console.log('ATTR2', interceptedObj.attr2)  // null
console.log('ABC', interceptedObj.abc)      // undefined
                         
interceptedObj.myfn1(1, 2, 3);
interceptedObj.myfn2(1, 2, 3);

// Function 'myfn1' started.
// executing myfn1 with [ 1, 2, 3 ]
// Function 'myfn1' finished.
// Function 'myfn2' started.
// executing myfn2 with [ 1, 2, 3 ]
// Function 'myfn2' finished.
```